# Converting between bases (wih decimal places) in java

Tags: java, numbers, decimal, decimal-point

I need to have java code that converts between different bases while conserving the decimal place.

What the program will do is take an input string that can be in either decimal, hexadecimal, binary or octal (the prog already knows what is what), and convert it into a double.

It does this with two numbers, and does a desired operation to them and outputs the finished number in the desired base (again, in any of the aforementioned bases)

I do not need help setting it up as much as figuring out how to convert the bases while conserving the decimal places, for precision. In all my searching, I cannot find anywhere an easy way to do this.

Basically, how can I convert between bases of numbers while keeping precision as high as possible (as much as is input)? 
(if i could, i would simply use a parseInt but it does not allow for any precision)

Comment: What you have tried? Please provide code so that we can find out what is going wrong

Comment: The only base that has decimal places is decimal. Other bases have other kinds of place: for example, binary has binary places. And binary places aren't commensurate with decimal places. In short, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: well that's the thing. I have everything except the conversion code. It works well for simple decimal because no converting is needed. 
my issue is that I cannot find anything on converting bases while keeping precision. 

Just some brainstorming ideas would be helpful

Comment: You will most likely need to seperate the integral and fractional parts and process them seperately.

Comment: @EJP not quite true, .25 is .01 in binary. It is possible , i am just not sure how to do it in code easily

Answer (score 1):

1. find out how many digits are after the point - let there are N digits.
2. Remove the point -this equivalent to multiplying by B^N, where B is the base.
3. Convert the input string as integer into double.
4. divide the resulting double by B^N.